# Dynamically ALTERing MySQL tables to add missing fields on INSERT

Tags: mysql, insert, field, alter

I'm attempting to merge data from one MySQL database into another. The problem is, some of the tables in `Source_DB` have fields that the matching table in `Target_DB` does not have.

Is there a way to automatically `ALTER` the table in `Target_DB` to add these missing fields as they are found?

Or should I go about it another way, like doing a first pass where I compare each table to first add any missing fields?

Comment: Or just insert the data from `Target_DB` into `Source_DB` and then rename the tables? :)

Comment: An interesting idea, though I am attempting to keep it a one-way operation for simplicity's sake. Also, I'm needing to merge the data as opposed to overwriting one table with the contents of another. Thank you for the idea!

Comment: Just a note that I found a very interesting PHP script for comparing schemas: http://joefreeman.co.uk/blog/2009/07/php-script-to-compare-mysql-database-schemas/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could query the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` on each DB and figure out what's missing with a NOT IN query and then using the data in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` dynamically generate the DDL.

Or you could use a tool like [MySQL Compare](http://mysql-compare.com/) to do it.

Comment: Very interesting tool, I'll give that a shot. Also thanks for pointing out INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS. That is very useful for getting the data needed for the ALTER. Thank you Conrad!